# Change of variable in univariate polynomials

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Given $ f(x) = a_{0} + a_{2} x^{2} +  \cdots + a_{n}  x^n $.

Define $ g(t) $ as $ f(15t -7) $.

How can I show that

$$ g(t) = b_{0} + b_{2} t^{2} +  \cdots + b_{n}  t^n $$

Do I need calculus for this?

Comment: You don't need calculus. Note that $(15t-7)^k$ is a k-degree polynomial (you can multiply it out using the binomial expansion.

Comment: use binomial theorem to expand out terms.

Comment: Thanks. Just multiply all out seems a bit messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the binomial theorem (or by the comment of Pedro),

$$(15t-7)^k$$ is a sum of powers of the two terms, with total degree $k$. Hence it is a polynomial in $t$ of degree $k$.

Now the original expression is a linear combination of such terms, hence it is also a polynomial in $t$, of maximum degree $n$.

---

By a similar reasoning,

$$f(g(t))$$ where $f$ is a polynomial of degree $d_f$, and $g$ a polynomial of degree $d_g$, is a polynomial of degree $d_fd_g$.